# Why is Syslog Not Writing Logs To The Designated Files?

Tags: ubuntu, logging, syslog, ubuntu-8.04

I've been trying to route Apache's logs through Syslog (for some reason log rotation had stopped, and using Syslog and logrotate seemed a reasonable solution).

I have sent Apache's error logs to local7 and piped the access logs to local6 via the logger program.

I want Syslog to write the error and access logs to `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and `/var/log/apache2/access.log` respectively.

To that end I have added the following to `/etc/syslog.conf`:

```
# Logging for Apache using local7 facility for error messages
# and local6 for access log
# Added 20/06/2010 by Chris Bunney
local7.*                        /var/log/apache2/error.log
local6.*                        /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

I know that the error and access logs are being sent to Syslog correctly because they are showing up in `/var/log/syslog`, however they are not being written to the files I want.

The original file permissions of the target files:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root adm       0 2010-06-20 23:01 access.log
```

The current file permissions of the target files that I have been using to try and rule out such things causing issues:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 syslog adm       0 2010-06-20 23:01 access.log
```

Everything looks fine to me, so **why aren't the messages Syslog is receiving being written to the files I want?** Have I missed something simple?

---

Full Output of `cat /etc/syslog.conf`:

```
#  /etc/syslog.conf     Configuration file for syslogd.
#
#                       For more information see syslog.conf(5)
#                       manpage.

#
# First some standard logfiles.  Log by facility.
#

auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
cron.*                          /var/log/cron.log
daemon.*                        -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.*                           -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log
user.*                          -/var/log/user.log

#
# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
#
mail.info                       -/var/log/mail.info
mail.warn                       -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err                        /var/log/mail.err

# Logging for INN news system
#
news.crit                       /var/log/news/news.crit
news.err                        /var/log/news/news.err
news.notice                     -/var/log/news/news.notice

# Logging for Apache using local7 facility for error messages
# and local6 for access log
# Added 20/06/2010 by Chris Bunney
local7.*                        /var/log/apache2/error.log
local6.*                        /var/log/apache2/access.log

#
# Some `catch-all' logfiles.
#
*.=debug;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        news.none;mail.none     -/var/log/debug
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        cron,daemon.none;\
        mail,news.none          -/var/log/messages

#
# Emergencies are sent to everybody logged in.
#
*.emerg                         *

#
# I like to have messages displayed on the console, but only on a virtual
# console I usually leave idle.
#
#daemon,mail.*;\
#       news.=crit;news.=err;news.=notice;\
#       *.=debug;*.=info;\
#       *.=notice;*.=warn       /dev/tty8

# The named pipe /dev/xconsole is for the `xconsole' utility.  To use it,
# you must invoke `xconsole' with the `-file' option:
#
#    $ xconsole -file /dev/xconsole [...]
#
# NOTE: adjust the list below, or you'll go crazy if you have a reasonably
#      busy site..
#
daemon.*;mail.*;\
        news.err;\
        *.=debug;*.=info;\
        *.=notice;*.=warn       |/dev/xconsole
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Did you restart syslogd? You can also use `lsof -f -p <pid-of-syslogd>` to see what log files it has open. The syslog.conf looks right, you might want to post your apache configuration.

Comment: Yep, I missed something simple. I must have restarted everything *but* syslog. Restarted Syslog and it worked fine. Sorry, but I don't have the rep for an upvote. Now, I think I ought to go to bed, the lack of sleep is obviously having negative effects...

Comment: I'm such a sad person. Restarting syslog doesn't solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 5):

For those lost in googling with similar symptoms after an update from Ubuntu LTS 12.04 to 14.04.1: syslog was replaced by rsyslog, which is for some reason not installed by the distribution-upgrade.

solution is to `apt-get install rsyslog`