# Ubuntu 10.04 syslog not logging to correct file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, syslog

In a similar vein to [Why is Syslog Not Writing Logs To The Designated Files?](https://serverfault.com/questions/153052/why-is-syslog-not-writing-logs-to-the-designated-files)

I'm having a few problems with syslog on Ubuntu 10.0.4

I have an app which I have set to facility local7.  I added the following line to `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`

```
local7.*    /var/log/my.log
```

I then force rsyslogd to reload the config files as follows:

```
pgrep syslogd # returns 817  
sudo kill -HUP 817
```

I run the following test:

```
$ logger local7.info hello
```

But the output appears in `/var/log/syslog`

Have I missed something?  This works fine on my dev machine (Mac OS X)

Comment: Additional information:  According to lsof, syslog does not have my.log open.

Answer (score 2):

> But the output appears in /var/log/syslog

Right, but does it also appear in `/var/log/my.log`.  Syslog daemons will send a matching log line to every file that has a has a matching filter.  In addition to adding the entry for the new file you also need to adjust the filter for `/var/log/syslog` so that it does not get `local7.*` messages.

Comment: It does not appear in my.log at all - that is my main problem

Comment: BTW, it should be `logger -p local7.info hello` to send something to `local7.info`.

Answer (score 0):

Add "local7.none" to the line that logs to /var/log/syslog and reload syslogd (a one-line quick way is "sudo killall -HUP syslogd").

Comment: I will give that a try.  THe output is not going to my.log though.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

sudo service rsyslog restart

It appears that rsyslog does not respond to HUP like syslogd does.